# How to format csv into multiline newline delimited plain text output using csvkit

Tags: csvkit

I have a csv like this,

```
type,name,ad1,pin,ph
"A","aaaaa","23 rd.","45789","4578954"
"F","bbbbb","23 rd.","84789","4578954"
"D","ccccc","34 rd.","45646","7845663"
```

this needs to be formatted to a plain text file like this.

```
type
name
ad1, PIN-pin
PH: ph
```

So the final output would be like this.

```
A
aaaaa
23 rd., PIN- 45789,
PH: 4578954

F
bbbbb
23 rd. PIN-84789
PH:4578954

D
ccccc
34 rd., PIN-45646
PH: 7845663
```

Is it possible to achieve this in csvkit.

Comment: If you are still interested I have a solution using Miller http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/

Comment: Please share the solution.

Comment: I have done https://stackoverflow.com/a/55529867/757714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0):

```
mlr --c2x --ops "\t" put '$1=$type;$2=$name;$3=($ad1 . ", PIN-" . $pin);$4=("PH: " . $ph)' \
then cut -r -f "^[0-9]" input.csv | \
cut -f2
```

to have

```
A
aaaaa
23 rd., PIN-45789
PH: 4578954

F
bbbbb
23 rd., PIN-84789
PH: 4578954

D
ccccc
34 rd., PIN-45646
PH: 7845663
```

Some notes:

- `--c2x` to convert csv to XTAB (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/file-formats.html#XTAB:_Vertical_tabular);
- `--ops` to set tab as pair separator
- `put` to set the field the way you want (I create 4 new fields, named 1, 2, 3 and 4)
- `cut` (before the pipe) to delete all fields except 1, 2, 3 and 4
- the final `cut` delete field names